# Use Tf-idf as features in CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf-idf

I've a CNN model that runs fine with word2vec matrix as input. Now, I'm trying to use tf-idf features as an input to my CNN model. My model has 2 convolution layers.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=10000, use_idf=True)
vectorizer = vectorizer.fit(train_sentences)
tf_len = len(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
TF_X_train = vectorizer.transform(train_sentences).astype('float64')
TF_X_test = vectorizer.transform(test_sentences).astype('float64')
TF_X_val = vectorizer.transform(val_sentences).astype('float64')


input = Input(shape=(tf_len,1))
drop20 = SpatialDropout1D(0.3)(input)
conv2 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(drop20)
drop21 = Dropout(0.5)(conv2)
conv22 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(drop21)
drop22 = Dropout(0.5)(conv22)
pool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(drop22)
flat2 = Flatten()(pool2)
out = Dense(8, activation='sigmoid')(flat2)

model = Model(input, out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

I got the following error. Please provide any hints to resolve my problem.

I've also tried to change input layer to `Input(batch_shape=(None,tf_len, 1))` but got the same error.

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 5008)

Comment: Try with `tf_len=tf_len.reshape(1,tf_len.shape[0],tf_len.shape[1])`

Comment: tf_len is an integer in my case. BTW, do you mean change ```input_shape``` to (1, number_of_documents, len_of_vocabulary)? or reshape my training data?

Comment: Sorry, I meant reshaping your training to data (which seems to be 2D) to 3D with the code in my previous answer (obviously using the correct values, not `tf_len`)

Comment: I did that but now got this. ***ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 1000 target samples.***

Comment: Then probably the order of the reshape is not the one expected, try and switch places between them and I believe you will get the required shape

Comment: Moving 1 to end of reshape ```TF_X_train.reshape(TF_X_train.shape[0], TF_X_train.shape[1],1)``` and chaging input layer to ```Input(batch_shape=(None, tf_len, 1))``` worked. Thanks a lot @celius stingher

Comment: @Mogambo , did you also have to reshape `TF_X_test` and `TF_X_val`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the Answer in this (Answer) Section, even though it is already present in the Comments Section.

Adding the below line of Code,

```
TF_X_train.reshape(TF_X_train.shape[0], TF_X_train.shape[1],1)
```

and changing input layer to

```
Input(batch_shape=(None, tf_len, 1))
```

has fixed the error.

Comment: Do you happen to know how if this would be the same process when concatenating other features with tfidf? So, if I have word overlap, would you just concatenate them with the tfidf, then reshape them the in a similar fashion? Then the tf_len would be the length of concatenated tfidf and other features?